# User uploaded pictures?

Tags: support, status-completed

Are users able to upload their own pictures into these diagrams on this site?

Answer (score 8):

You need to have a reputation of 10 or more to be able to post pictures.

The [privilege page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/privileges) explains them all. The [new user privilege](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/privileges/new-user) is the on that covers this.

In the meantime just post a link to the image and some one with edit rights will convert it into an inline image for you.

If you post good questions and answers you'll soon gain the reputation you need.

Answer (score 2):

Sure -- as long as you have more than 10 rep, you can add images. Use the image button on the toolbar to do so.

[image]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/native-image-uploads-imgur.png))</sub>